# Vertical centering issue with flexbox and CSS3 width/height declarations

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm trying to vertically center a nav element and stick it to the right of the screen however there is something pushing it down just a bit off center.

[image]

The red is the flex container, the green is the header and the grey box is the right aligned and vertically centered box I want to be ACTUALLY vertically centered and not 'off-center'.

I can't figure out what is making it jump down.

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L4u9t78m/1/) so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. (Essentially it's a fixed flex container that sits over a scrolling page.

```
<div class="navWrap"><!-- Place less important HTML after main content (My brain hurts!)-->

            <header>

                <nav>
                </nav>

            </header>

            <nav class="pagesNav next">

                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class="arrow"></span>

            </nav>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navWrap {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center; 

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 

    background: red;
}

header {
    -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    align-self: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: green;
}

nav:not(.pagesNav) {
}

.pagesNav { 
    margin-left: auto;

    width: 80px;
    height: 155px;

    background: #414141;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your header in the wrong place, try this

```
<div class="pageWrap"><!-- Primary content first for SEO purposes. Use CSS to rearrange secondary elements -->


          <header>

                <nav>
                </nav>

        </header>
     <main role="main">

                <section></section>
                <section></section>
                <section></section>
                <section></section>

            </main>

            <footer>
            </footer>

        </div>

        <div class="navWrap"><!-- Place less important HTML after main content (My brain hurts!)-->


            <nav class="pagesNav next">

                <span class="arrow"></span>
                <span class="arrow"></span>

            </nav>

        </div>
```

css

```
    html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {

}

/* Temp styles */

.pageWrap {

}

main {
    max-width: 1920px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
}

section:first-child {
    height: 95vh;
}

section:nth-child(even) {
    background: yellow;
}

footer {
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
}

/* Less important info */
header{
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center; 

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;   

}
.navWrap {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center; 

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 
}

header {
    -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-item-align: start;
    align-self: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: green;
}

nav:not(.pagesNav) {
}

.pagesNav { 
    margin-left: auto;

    width: 80px;
    height: 155px;

    background: #414141;
}
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L4u9t78m/2/

Comment: I understand I can make my life easier by placing the header first but my goal is to be as SEO friendly as possible so surely i can, using the power of CSS, arrange the HTML anyway I want then rearrange using CSS.

I can't see why that would affect my layout. The 'navWrap' is its own container

Comment: You never, said SEO was a concern in your question. Besides, it really will not effect your SEO lol. (SEO is a myth)

Comment: Ahh crap I did miss that out. SEO is a concern but a minor change like that probably won't affect it right?

Comment: If you keep your html clean, you really will never have a problem with the "mythical seo". Search engines like google use a ton of variables when it comes too a search, a users location has more to do with the results than the seo ever will.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice man - I will implement tomorrow and mark as correct since your JSFIDDLE works.